# How to create a certain number of items in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, integer

Is there any way to make my java app create a certain number of items in an array based on the value of an integer?

EDIT: I did not make my question clear. Here is what I actually meant:

Here's my code:

```
Loader loader = new Loader();
```

Basically what I want to do is list the constructors I want to call in a text file. My app will read each line and replace "Loader" with the constructor that I want to call. I already have it set so that it will add every line in the text file to an array:

```
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("modEnable.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String str;

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
            list.add(str);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Short answer, yes.  You will probably need a loop of some kind and the value you want to add...and hopefully not overflow the array...

Comment: I will strongly suggest OP to get a introductory book of Java programming.  Array should be something that is covered in first few chapters

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about this:

```
public int createArray(int num, int value) {
  int[] a = new int[num];
  Arrays.fill(a, value);
  return a;
}
```